# Is there an SQLite function to return only a substring/partial value

Tags: sqlite

For the following query

namelist

```
name
Thisismy/$name
Thisisalsomy/$name
Thisisnotmy/$name


SELECT name from namelist;
```

returns

```
Thisismy/$name
Thisisalsomy/$name
Thisisnotmy/$name
```

How can I limit the return to everything up to the /

ie:

```
Thisismy
Thisisalsomy
Thisisnotmy
```

Comment: probably need better re-format for data you have in the question, so along the line like `namelist` is the table name, and probably need to clarify what these are  `Thisismy/$name Thisisalsomy/$name ...` and others. This is not for me but for other readers to be more flexible to digest the question and able to help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks haxpor . First time posting. Appreciate the helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with some sqlite [core functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
sqlite> select substr('Thisisalsomy/$name',0,instr('Thisisalsomy/$name','/'));
Thisisalsomy
```

So

```
SELECT substr(name,0,instr(name,'/')) from namelist;
```

Tested as follows:

```
sqlite> create table namelist (name);
sqlite> insert into namelist values ('Thisismy/$name'),('Thisisalsomy/$name'),('Thisisnotmy/$name');
sqlite> SELECT name from namelist;
Thisismy/$name
Thisisalsomy/$name
Thisisnotmy/$name
sqlite> SELECT substr(name,0,instr(name,'/')) from namelist;
Thisismy
Thisisalsomy
Thisisnotmy
sqlite>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. You've really helped me.